# webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl no longer works on 12.0.1

Tags: webdriver-manager

I'm getting an error when performing the following in 12.0.1:

> webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl

It just returns

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
```

I tried with an older version and it works fine

```
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 10.2.5
[13:51:46] I/downloader - ignoring SSL certificate
[13:51:46] I/downloader - ignoring SSL certificate
[13:51:46] I/downloader - ignoring SSL certificate
```

Comment: Hrrrrrmmm... create an issue on github. Also in your issue, explain your environment and why you need to ignore ssl.

Comment: Thanks, I initially planned on doing that but the Contribution guidelines stated it will be closed by default with a post stating to please raise on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, main reason I need to ignore SSL is because I'm behind a corporate firewall that overrides certificates with their own self-signed certificate. This presents a lot of issues with many of the node packages today.

Comment: The contributing is if there is an issue with the framework and that support questions should go on StackOverflow. Since I sort of look over that repository, I'll investigate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the recent rework to the binary class was not passing the optional parameters including `opt_proxy` and `opt_ignoreSSl` when calling `webdriver-manager update`. When [angular/webdriver PR #208](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/pull/208) is merged and released, this should be fixed.

Update: this has been merged and should have a release soon.

Comment: is this the reason that `webdriver-manager update --proxy http://proxy:8080` is no longer working? The proxy option looks like it is being ignored.

Comment: Try again. with 12.0.4. I grabbed the versionList before I set the proxy. This means it would try to make the first request without the proxy. Face palm! Just released a few minutes ago. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm using webdriver-manager 12.10 and --ignore_ssl is working fine on my end!